# Failed to load sigar-amd64-winnt: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, sigar

I'm new to sigar and native library programming in java, so maybe it is just a simple problem, but I can't find a result on my own.
I'm using eclipse indigo on a win 7 (64bit) OS. I've taken the following steps:

Add sigar.jar an log4l.jar to the jre6/lib, add the sigar-amd64-winnt.dll (also the files for x86) file to ./Program Files/Java/jre6/lib.
Then I only want to create a new sigar() but get the following exception:

```
Failed to load sigar-amd64-winnt: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: Failed to load sigar-amd64-winnt: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.loadLibrary(Sigar.java:170)
    at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.<clinit>(Sigar.java:100)
    at MemExample.<clinit>(MemExample.java:8)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.hyperic.sigar.Mem.gather(Lorg/hyperic/sigar/Sigar;)V
    at org.hyperic.sigar.Mem.gather(Native Method)
    at org.hyperic.sigar.Mem.fetch(Mem.java:30)
    at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getMem(Sigar.java:304)
    at MemExample.getInformationsAboutMemor
```

I've already tried to manipulate the VM-Arguments (in `Run Config -DJava.library.path="path/of/lib"`), to set the native library in the java build path to the path of sigar/lib and to set the Systempath in the program on my own with `System.setProperty("path", "-")`. All of which are unsuccessful until now.
And step by step I yield to despair.

**Edit:**Is it possible that sigar only works with AMD?
Some friend tried the same code with an AMD processor and win 7 (32b) and it works.
I already look for an answer in the hyperic sigar developer forum, but I can't find any useful tips or answers.

Comment: Don't put Jars or natives into any JRE.  Add them to the run-time class-path or library path.

Comment: Where did you put the dll? Because there is a good chance the dll is not in the correct path.

Comment: The Question is, how can i get the programm to work.
the .dll file got in the Java/jre6/lib container.

Comment: Does anyone knows if there any dependent for amd processor?
Cause i'm using intel.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that sigar-amd64-winnt.lib is missing: http://communities.vmware.com/message/1947455#1947455